# Trouble installing fast_xor Gem on Ubuntu for Discourse

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm, ubuntu-12.10, ruby-2.0

I'm very new to terms like ruby, rvm, gems; but I'm trying to get Discourse installed on an Ubuntu 12.10 server. I have all gems installed using `bundle install`, save for one, `fast_xor`:

```
Installing fast_xor (1.1.1) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
compiling xor.c
xor.c: In function ‘string_xor’:
xor.c:28:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
xor.c:45:7: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
linking shared-object xor.so

make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 xor.so /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/fast_xor-1.1.1/lib/fast_xor
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/fast_xor-1.1.1/lib/fast_xor': No such file or directory
make: *** [install-so] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/fast_xor-1.1.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/fast_xor-1.1.1/ext/xor/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing fast_xor (1.1.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install fast_xor -v '1.1.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have checked out the `fast_xor` project from Git, but I receive a similar error when compiling from source.

An `rvm list` only lists one version of Ruby:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-245-40-185:~/discourse$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I'm not sure where to go from here?

Comment: Installed the gem on Ubuntu 12.04, also built with no problem. Do you have a chance to switch on 12,04. Plus, it's LTS, which means it's supported until 2017.

Comment: I think the error message means one of the directories in the path `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/fast_xor-1.1.1/lib/fast_xor` does not exist.

Comment: @tc Correct, the `/lib/` directory did not exist - but even when I create it manually prior to attempting to install the Gem, it seems some part of the build process removes the directory, as after the failed build, the directory is missing.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It's a bug in the gem: https://github.com/CodeMonkeySteve/fast_xor/issues/5

Always check the issue tracker of a project before asking questions - stavkoverflow is for solving problems not reporting bugs.

Comment: That issue was opened 12 hours ago, 6 hours *after* I asked my question. I appreciate the answer, but there's no need for a reprimanding. :)

Answer (score 4):

In your `Gemfile` replace the line:

```
gem 'fast_xor'
```

For the following one (to pull fast_xor from the Git repository, which has the bug fixed):

```
gem "fast_xor", :git => "git://github.com/CodeMonkeySteve/fast_xor.git"
```

If for whatever reason the git protocol is firewalled in your network (as is my case), then you can replace it with HTTPS:

```
gem "fast_xor", :git => "https://github.com/CodeMonkeySteve/fast_xor.git"
```